# How can I check the size of image in cnn model?

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, torch, dataloader

How can I check the **image shape** in this code?

```
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNetwork,self).__init__()
        self.ConvLayer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1,padding=1),
            nn.Conv2d(6, 12, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1,padding=1),
            nn.ReLU()
            )
......

def forward(self,x):
        x = self.ConvLayer1(x)

.....

        output = self.func(x)
        return output
```

I used this, but this is giving me an error.

```
self.ConvLayer1.weight.shape
```

Comment: Do you want the shape of the output `x` of `ConvLayer1` or do you want the shape of its weights?

Comment: I want to know the shape of the output x of ConvLayer1

Comment: `x.shape` should do the trick

Comment: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: https://github.com/tulikakakati/DEGnext/blob/main/general-learning/DEGnext_exp_1.py here is the full code pls check.

Comment: I see your code. You have to call `x.shape` inside the `forward` function of your model.

Comment: how can I check the summary of a model? pls let me know